# Send email with variable as subject

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sendmail

I've tried the following code

```
export HOST=`cat /etc/hostname`

function send {
  #$count is defined
  if [ $count != "0" ]; then
    #send mail
    /bin/echo "Hello world"|/usr/bin/mail -s "$HOST - server: Count = $count" -aFrom:noreply\<noreply@dummy.com\> dummy@email.com
  fi
}
```

After I edited the subject to include $HOST the script stopped sending emails

Comment: Stopped receiving all e-mails, or the script stopped sending emails?

Comment: Edit question to show the simplest script that works (I think you can remove conditionals), and the simplest that does not work (the smallest modification of the first). AND Have you put it through `shellcheck`?

Comment: Welcome, `-aFrom:` shouldn't be `-a From:`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity
Maybe but I don't think this is the issue

Comment: Is there any difference if you change 'export HOST=\`cat /etc/hostname\`' to `export HOST="$(cat /etc/hostname)"`?